# How to find files that are not owned by any package?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

In my system I have files that not belong to any package, they are mine or from compiled programs installed with `make install`. How can I find all files that do not belong to any package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `/var/lib/dpkg/info` are `.list` text files that list all the files contained in each package¹ installed through Debian's package manager.

Finding all files in the filesystem not matching any entry there can be achieved with something naïve like this:

```
find / -xdev -type f \( -exec grep -xq "{}" /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list \; -or -print \)
```

This will obviously take a very long time as the whole filesystem will be scanned.  If you use different partitions for system directories (such as `/usr` or `/var`), specify them after the initial `/`.

Warning: That does *not* include files created by package scripts. For instance:

- `/etc/hosts.allow` is not listed anywhere but it might come from `libwrap0` that possibly created it, if that file didn't exist at time of the package installation.
- Many files are compiled during installation, for example `.pyc` files (compiled Python libraries), `.elc` files (compiled Emacs Lisp librarires), etc.
- …

Comment: error `find: argument list too long`

Comment: @naught101 That suggests there are a gazillion files matching `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list` — above query would need to be rewritten under some other principle.

Answer (score 11):

A more efficient version of [@Patrice's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153272), using a shell with support for process substitution (`bash`, AT&T `ksh`, `zsh`):

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  comm -23 <(find / -xdev -type f | sort) \
           <(sort -u /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list)
)
```

Like Patrice's solution, it assumes no file path contains newline characters.

Comment: Would using the `locate` database be faster than running `find`? `locate \* | grep -v "^/home/"` - also has the benefit of looking in `/boot/` and other system partitions.

Answer (score 11):

Since you tagged your question with `debian` the obvious choice not mentioned yet is to use `cruft-ng` if you don't require any flexibility or `cruft` if you don't want to search through the whole system/locatedb.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use process substitution & `grep` & `find`. Note that the `grep` is used twice to filter only relevant paths from `/var/lib/dpkg/info` to save few seconds if you are looking for files in a certain directory.

```
dir="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
find "$dir" -type f \
| grep -v -x -F -f \
    <(find '/var/lib/dpkg/info' -name '*.list' -print0 \
       | xargs -0 grep -h -F "^$dir" \
       | sort -u)
```