# Moved /bin contents to /usr/bin, possible to undo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mv

Running Ubuntu 17.04, I was installing a software from non-repository distribution, I was supposed to move the software bin -folder contents to /usr/bin (which was already iffy advice)

It's one of those days, so what I did instead:

```
mv /bin/* /usr/bin
```

So I screwed up and I accidentally moved all the files in bin to /usr/bin and /bin was empty. Since I take that /bin is system critical, for quick remedy, I copied /usr/bin contents to /bin.

Now my /bin and /usr/bin contents identical and both contain the files originally in /bin and /usr/bin separated.

1. Is my Ubuntu in a broken state now? (Did not try to reboot the computer yet, right now everything seems to still work)
2. Is there a way to know which files have been moved/copied to /usr/bin most recently, so I could just manually take care of the situation?
   2.1 Are there usually overlapping files in /bin and /usr/bin
3. Is there other ways to undo what I did?

I don't have Timeshift installed so restoring backups is not an option, but there's nothing critical on the computer currently, so I could just admit to screwup reinstall the whole linux partition.

Comment: Temporary fix: `for f in /usr/bin/*; do ln -s "$f" /bin; done`.  Then use `apt-<mumble>` to find out which binaries belong in `/bin` and replace the symlinks.  Or just restore from backups.

Comment: dpkg-query -l | awk '{ system("dpkg-query -L "$2" | grep -E \"^/usr/bin/.*$\"") }' This will give you all the files initially in /usr/bin based on the packages installed

Comment: Can you add output of `ls -l /` ?

Comment: @SatōKatsura `/bin` is system critical. Its content must be present at the earliest boot stages. You don't want to create a symbolic link to a partition (`/usr` here) which may not be mounted at boot.

Comment: @xhienne I never said it would survive a reboot.  It's a temporary fix, to get enough functionality to be able to repair the system.

Comment: @Kusalananda It's probably easier to reinstall the OS than it is to try restoring fundamental OS components such as binaries in `/bin` from backup (what happens to running processes when the existing binary/library gets overwritten?).  I personally like "backup your data, reinstall the OS" as I think OS installations should be throw-away.

Comment: @xhienne that depends on how you set up the distro. Arch, for example, doesn't maintain a separate `/bin` by default. Ubuntu's default partitioning does not make separate `/usr` partitions. I'm curious as to how many people actually do make a separate `/usr` with a modern distro.

Comment: Over on Ask Ubuntu: [Accidentally removed /bin. How do I restore it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/906674/158442) (which is a more complicated case)

Comment: @SatōKatsura & muru: What I'm mentioning is stated by the FHS which is followed by Debian-like systems. Nobody is forced to partition in a certain way. But you must not assume the partition does not exist, that's why I reacted to Sato's comment. In absence of any information, you can not make such a statement without warnings. Moreover, the OP had copied everything from `/usr/bin` to `/bin`, that makes those symbolic links even more irrelevant.

Comment: @xhienne there is information: "reinstall the whole linux *partition*" (singular) which strongly indicates a single-partition setup (or the default setup, where `/boot` might be a different partition depending on which automatic installation option was chosen).

Comment: @muru Take my comment as a generic one. You may assume whatever you want on the number of partitions, I prefer not to and I'm warning against linking /usr/bin/* to /bin, which at best is completely useless and at worst may render the system unusable at next boot. No system that follows the FHS should contain symlinks to /usr/bin. OP was well-advised to copy the files instead.

Comment: @xhienne The FHS doesn't require that files in `/bin` not be symlinks to `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @muru You should read the FHS and my comment better. Neither the FHS nor me are saying it's forbidden to put symlinks in /bin. We both say that binaries that are essential for booting must be in /bin (and libraries in /lib for the same reason). Of course you can have symlinks, but your symlinks must point to binaries in /bin, not in /usr/bin

Comment: @xhienne "your symlinks must point to binaries in /bin" And FHS doesn't say anything like that. You can interpret FHS's statements about symlinks in `/bin` that way, I don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65838/discussion-between-xhienne-and-muru).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is my Ubuntu in a broken state now?

Yes, **your Ubuntu is broken**

You messed up something important to [package management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager).

So in practice, backup your important data (at least `/etc` and `/home`), perhaps also the list of installed packages e.g. output of `dpkg -l`, and reinstall Ubuntu.

<sup>(a non-novice could try to manage - like in other answers -, but then he would not have done such a huge and basic mistake)</sup>

> I could just admit to screwup reinstall the whole linux partition.

That is probably what would consume less of your time. Keeping your current system with the help of other answers is keeping it in a very messy state (which would give you future headaches).

Since you are reformatting your disk, consider putting `/home` in a separate partition (so future such mistakes won't lose your data). Before doing that print on paper the output of `df -h` and `df -hi` and `fdisk -l` (they give information about disk space -both used and available-  ...). Be wise to have a large enough system partition (the root file system); if you can afford it 100 Gbytes is more than enough.

> I was supposed to move the software bin -folder contents to /usr/bin

(terminology: Unix have directories, not "folders").

That (*moving* to `/usr/bin/`) is very wrong. Either improve your [$PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (preferably) or at most add *symlinks* in `/usr/bin/` and preferably move (or add symlinks) executables to `/usr/local/bin/`.

The wise approach is to never change `/usr/bin/`, `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin/`  outside of package management tools (e.g. `dpkg`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, etc...). Read the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: Going to accept this answer: it seems that after trying to recover it worked until reboot, which was unable to launch any desktop environment session anymore. Rather than trying to fix that, I'll admit my total screw up and will just reinstall the linux partition. Since everything was on version control and I had used the system for only a week, all I really lost was my dignity and had a small panic attack, but that seems to be normal when life teaches me a lesson.

Comment: Why the panic attack? You could still issue shell commands

Comment: As `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are now identical, I am not sure why package management would be screwed up. Is there really a case where `/bin/foo` and `/usr/bin/foo` are both provided by a package(s). If not, there are just some extra files floating around.

Comment: A later `apt-get update` might be unhappy with the present `/bin`

Comment: So, why not rm -rf /bin ; ln -s /usr/bin /bin ?

Comment: @Basile no it wouldn’t (be unhappy); package management only cares about files it knows about, it won’t complain about files it doesn’t know about. Even for files it *does* know about, it won’t be particularly bothered if they’ve changed...

Comment: @Basile also I wouldn’t count on the latter part “(a non-novice could try to manage - like in other answers -, but then he would not have done such a huge and basic mistake)” being true ;-). Even experts slip up sometimes!

Comment: Ok, but then they would not ask that question in the way it has been asked

Comment: FWIW my main system's `/` partition is 12GB and I never ran into space issue despite using it for development (read header files and many tools) office and design (read heavy tools), on KDE (read not-the-slimmest). Throw in 4GB more if you don't split `/var`, inflate by 25% if you want a larger margin than I have, and at 20GB you're more than good.

Answer (score 35):

On Linux (and on most other systems, though POSIX doesn't give you that guarantee unless the move was across file systems), that would have updated their ctime, so assuming none of the other ones in `/usr/bin` have been touched in the last 24 hours, you should be able to move them back with:

```
find /usr/bin/. ! -name . -prune -ctime -1 -exec sh -c '
   echo mv -i "$@" /bin' sh {} +
```

Remove the `echo` if that looks right. Note that you won't be able to recover the files that existed by the same name in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` (the original ones in `/usr/bin` would have been lost)

A potential caveat: if some files were hard linked in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, all the hard links in `/usr/bin` would be moved to `/bin`.

Now, you may think that since `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are in the default `$PATH`, and `/bin` is available on `/boot` at least before `/usr` is mounted, it should not matter whether the executables are in `/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`.

But that would be overlooking that many commands hard code the paths of executables and expect them to be in some specific case. A common case is she-bangs. All scripts that have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

will fail to work after you do `mv /usr/bin/env /bin/env`. In that regard, having the commands in both locations is safer in that it won't break those scripts.

Comment: As alluded to above (I removed my comment as it had a serious error that would try to move everything to a directory called `i`--sorry about that!) on GNU/Linux systems like Ubuntu one may use `find /usr/bin/. ! -name . -prune -ctime -1 -exec echo mv -it /bin {} +` since [GNU Coreutils `mv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html) supports `-t`. Other OSes [don't generally support it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html), nor does it work in [the alternate `mv` provided by BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html).

Answer (score 17):

1. Your installation should be mostly OK; there shouldn’t be different files with the same name in `/usr` and `/usr/bin` (which answers your 2.1), so having all the files in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin` won’t break anything (until you upgrade packages). The only problem you might have now is broken symlinks, if you overwrote a binary with a symlink to it. To fix this, look for broken symlinks:

   ```
   find -L /bin /usr/bin -type l -ls
   ```

   and reinstall any packages corresponding to the files listed (for example, if `/usr/bin/zsh` shows up as broken, `dpkg -S /bin/zsh /usr/bin/zsh` will tell you which package the file came from; reinstall it with `apt --reinstall install zsh`).
2. You can show and sort by ctime to see files which were recently changed (which will include files you moved):

   ```
   ls -ltc /bin
   ```
3. The best approach to undo what you did is use the `cruft` package and delete files it finds in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` which don’t come from a package:

   ```
   sudo apt install cruft
   sudo cruft -d "/ /usr"
   ```

   unless the files are symlinks to files in `/etc/alternatives` (in which case you should leave them alone).

Comment: Except for scripts that start with `#! /bin/sh` or similar.

Comment: @SatōKatsura they would still work fine if `sh` is in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin` (all the files are duplicated now).

Comment: A special toolk like `cruft` is not necessary for this job because the package manager also keeps track of installed files. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153260/how-to-find-files-that-are-not-owned-by-any-package .

Comment: `comm -12 <(ls /bin) <(ls /usr/bin)` show a few entries on a Ubuntu system I tested it on. Some with a `/bin/foo -> /usr/bin/foo` which means `foo` would have been lost.

Comment: @Stéphane ah yes, moving the link would nuke the original...

Comment: @Ned64 except that the package manager doesn’t keep track of everything (*e.g.* alternatives). Try running `dpkg -S /usr/bin/*|&grep "no path found matching"` — you’ll see there are lots of files which `dpkg` doesn’t know about but that definitely come from packages.

Comment: @Stéphane although the links should go the other way (`/usr/bin` to `/bin`, see `ksh` or `zsh` for example).

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks - I do not have Ubuntu so that I cannot check. I would expect the remaining few items to be negligible - one run of `update-alternatives` should cover that.

Comment: @Ned64 no, because `update-alternatives` won’t delete symlinks it doesn’t know about. On the Debian system I checked this on, I have 366 untracked binaries in `/usr/bin`, which isn’t really negligible...

Comment: Following Stéphanes advice and then 'find -L /bin /usr/bin -type l -ls' , the only output is a fileloop warning of X11, which is supposed to be symlink back to /usr/bin. Anything else I should consider?

Comment: @oneOfThoseDays you could check the output of `dpkg -S /bin/* /usr/bin/*|&grep "no path found matching"` (ignoring links); apart from that, you should be OK — the important thing is to not leave untracked binaries lying around, since they won’t be upgraded when the package they originally came from is upgraded.

Answer (score 6):

It may be educational to elaborate just *why* your system is, to a greater or lesser extent, ‘broken’.

1. As @basile-starynkevitch points out, the package management system has the potential to get terribly confused if it finds binaries in `/bin` when they should be in `/usr/bin`, and vice versa.
2. Some (possibly important) scripts may be hard-wired to find a particular binary in one directory or the other (in some circumstances it's good practice, for example from a security point of view, *not* to rely on the contents of the `$PATH`).
3. The reason why there is a distinction between `/bin` and `/usr/bin` is that the former may potentially be on a partition which is mounted at an earlier stage of the boot.  In this context (ie, when booting the system), not only would `/bin/xxx` binaries probably be referred to by a full path, but the directory `/usr/bin` might not be available on the system at that point. (If you `df /bin` and `df /usr/bin`, you may see the same filesystem listed, or different ones; probably most default installs, these days, leave both directories in the same partition).

Thus you can doubless see that, if you have the *same* binaries in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, then problems 2 and 3 won't occur, and the damage from 1 might be minor.  Re 1, for example, packages might not be properly uninstalled if you try to remove them; and upgrades might become garbled, if the upgrade tries to upgrade the copy in the ‘correct’ place, but ignores the copy in the ‘wrong’ place.  Thus, if the above remedies seem too drastic or complicated, you *might* get away with leaving the system in this state.

But if this is an important system, I **really** wouldn't bank on that.

A general rule (again echoing @basile-starynkevitch) is never to monkey with `/usr/bin`, `/bin` and friends – they ‘belong’ to the distribution – and a package which suggests doing so as part of its normal install is... not a good package.

*Edit:* Relevant to point 3, there's a [discussion in the context of systemd/Fedora and friends](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/) of why it makes sense to move all the contents of `/bin` to `/usr/bin`, and symlink the first to the second.  This is *not* a recommendation that you do this, yourself – that page is addressed to the people who make distributions – but it includes some history of why this distinction exists (and by implication why it is now merely dusty tradition).