# Are {/bin, /lib, /sbin} symlinks into /usr in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, fhs

I am a little confused by this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393142/22724) about moving files from `/bin` to `/usr/bin` on an Ubuntu 17.04 system. Reading the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/Quantal/UsrMerge) says:

> For Quantal, merged /usr should be supported. On new systems installer should create {/bin, /lib, /sbin} symlinks into /usr.

As this was from 2012 and I do not have an Ubuntu chroot, can someone tell me if the default is for a merged `/usr` and if not, if there is newer documentation that I am missing.

Comment: I run ubuntu xenial, and `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are distinct directories, neither symlinked nor bind-mounted to the other.

Comment: Have you considered asking on some Ubuntu forum?