# Can't restore systemd after upgrade from Debian 10 to 11: “undefined symbol: seccomp_api_get”

Tags: debian, systemd, apt

I upgraded from Debian 10 to 11 one week ago.

The recurring error is:

```
symbol lookup error: /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-247.so: undefined symbol: seccomp_api_get
```

It caused a kernel panic when booting the system.

I had to switch to systemv as the init system.

Now, when I try to restore `systemd`, I have the following error:

```
root@nas:~# apt install systemd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
systemd is already the newest version (247.3-6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up systemd (247.3-6) ...
systemd-machine-id-setup: symbol lookup error: /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-247.so: undefined symbol: seccomp_api_get
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My versions:

```
root@nas:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
root@nas:~# uname -a
Linux nas 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=944726#29):

> I had the same problem. The cause were some old libs in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, especially a libseccomp. They are not package-managed (i.e. they don't belong to any package). […]
>
> The new libseccomp2 package shipped new binaries to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu but the runtime loader loaded the old version in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. […]
>
> The problem disappears if either I remove the old libs from
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

So I deleted these files:

```bash
rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2*
```

And I was able to switch back to Systemd.

### How to check it

You can use `dpkg --search` and it will tell if a file or directory is orphaned:

```
dpkg --search /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2
```

You can find files without corresponding packages with `cruft-ng`: [How to find files that are not owned by any package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153260/how-to-find-files-that-are-not-owned-by-any-package/491330#491330)

---

### Update

There is a [symlink between `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/750734/50687), so search in both directories before deciding to remove something.

I ran `dpkg --search /usr/lib/terminfo/` and it returned a warning, so I removed the directory and it midly broke the CLI, because it is in fact a dependency of `ncurses-base`.

Searching in `/usr/lib/` and `/lib/` gives the package that own this directory.

```
dpkg --search /usr/lib/terminfo/ /lib/terminfo/
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/terminfo/
ncurses-base: /lib/terminfo
```

So we must not rely on one search from `dpkg --search` to decide if it's safe to remove data.

Comment: Thank you.  I was upgrading an old netgear readynas box and `sudo rm /lib/*/libseccomp.so.2*` did the trick for me.