# After upgrading to Debian 12, duplicated files in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, dist-upgrade

I just upgraded my system from Debian 11 to 12, by following this [guide from cyberciti](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/update-upgrade-debian-11-to-debian-12-bookworm/). This system has been kept up-to-date for more than 9 years, so it has been through at least 4 major upgrades (Debian 7 or 8 to 12 today).

During the first run of `apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs`, I had an error about `libudev` (sadly I forgot to keep the output from the command), that I fixed by removing 2 files:

```
$ rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.5
```

I was able to finish the upgrade and reboot.

---

By performing further investigation, it looks like my system has some other duplicated libraries:

```
$ dpkg --search /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/
libperl5.36:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl
```

It looks like these directories are not symbolic links:

```
$ ls -ld /lib/ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ /usr/ /usr/lib/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
drwxr-xr-x 84 root root 4.0K Jul  5 21:05 /lib//
drwxr-xr-x 78 root root  96K Jul  5 21:05 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4.0K Jul  5 20:32 /usr//
drwxr-xr-x 84 root root 4.0K Jul  5 21:05 /usr/lib//
drwxr-xr-x 78 root root  96K Jul  5 21:05 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//
```

I already had a very similar issue before: [Can't restore systemd after upgrade from Debian 10 to 11: “undefined symbol: seccomp_api_get”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/677142/50687)

---

Here are the questions:

1. Is it normal to have duplicated libraries in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`
2. Can I rely on the output of `dpkg --search` and delete the paths that show `no path found …`? Or can some tool help me clean this mess?
3. What events on my system could have made this possible?

Update: actually it looks like there 2 directories are identical:

```
$ ls -lh /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore
ls: cannot access '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore': No such file or directory
$ touch /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore
$ ls -lh /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 22:14 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 22:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/test.ignore
```

But I don't understand how it works. And now I know that I must not delete files from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` because it would delete files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` too.

Comment: `/lib` has just been a symlink to `/usr/lib` on new Debian installs [since Debian 10](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#merged-usr), and on upgraded systems since [Debian 12](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge) or whenever they install the `usrmerge` package.

Comment: @hobbs thanks for the answer and the links, is it possible that my system failed the merge in the past? I can't see that symlink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see a symlink, you mustn’t add `/`:

```
ls -ld /lib
```

should show you a different result.

Debian 12 [enforces a “merged `/usr`”](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#a-merged-usr-is-now-required), the “duplication” you’re seeing is normal.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the answer from Stephen Kitt, here are the answers to my question:

> 1. Is it normal to have duplicated libraries in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Yes, there is a symlink:

```
$ ls -ld /lib /usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Jul  5 20:34 /lib -> usr/lib/
drwxr-xr-x 75 root root 4096 Jul  6 00:42 /usr/lib/
```

> 2. Can I rely on the output of `dpkg --search` and delete the paths that show `no path found …`? Or can some tool help me clean this mess?

No, using `dpkg --search` on `/lib` only give irrelevant results, because some files are installed on `/usr/lib/`:

```
$ dpkg --search /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/cross-config-5.36.0/Config.pm \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/cross-config-5.36.0/Config.pm
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/cross-config-5.36.0/Config.pm
libperl5.36:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/cross-config-5.36.0/Config.pm
```

Removing the file `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/cross-config-5.36.0/Config.pm` would remove the file in `/usr/lib`, which can break the whole system.

> 3. What events on my system could have made this possible?

As explained on the link shared by Stephen, the symlink from `/lib` to `/usr/lib/` is normal on Debian 12.